# ASP.NET MVC EF Migration Foreign Key error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two classes that have a 1 to many relationship which are `Format` class and `Exam` class. Thus, I use the **Code First Migrations** to add the navigation properties for each classes as well as a `Foreign Key` property. However, when I enter the command `update-database`, it presents me with this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Exams_dbo.ExamFormats_ExamFormatID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-ExamBankSys-20161202012850", table "dbo.ExamFormats", column 'id'.

**Format Model**

```
public class ExamFormat
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string FormatDesc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}
```

**Exam Model**

```
public class Exam
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }

    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExamFormat")]
    public int ExamFormatID { get; set; }
    public virtual ExamFormat ExamFormat { get; set; }
}
```

It works for the `public int ModuleId` with the navigation property of `Module`. However, the `migration` does not work for the class `ExamFormat` even when I specify the `[ForeignKey]` annotation. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you profile your migration so that you can see your actual executed query? You should see something like `ALTER TABLE Exam ...` that generated received error. Possible cause is to add column as not null with default(0) and crash with FK.

Comment: Could you try removing the `ForeignKey` attribute from the foreign key and add it to the navigational property? `[ForeignKey("ExamFormatID")]public virtual ExamFormat ExamFormat { get; set; }`

Comment: @Developer still not working

Comment: Do you have existing data in Exam? If so you may need to initially set the relationship up as optional (as Alexei mentions), then make it required in a second step.

Comment: @SteveGreene Thank you for your feedback and yes I do have existing data in Exam thus having the mandatory relationship causes the error.

Comment: See [this](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2015/04/entity-framework-non-null-foreign-key-migration/)